The free product has the direct product as a factor group. What's the corresponding normal subgroup?
Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. Consider the free product $G * H$ and the direct product $G \times H$. There is a particular way of identifying $G \times H$ as a factor group of $G * H$. Namely, the quotient map $f : G * H \to G \times H$ is recursively defined as:
$$
\forall g \in G \quad \forall x \in G * H \quad f(g \cdot x) = (g, e_H) \cdot f(x)
$$
$$
\forall h \in H \quad \forall x \in G * H \quad f(h \cdot x) = (e_G, h) \cdot f(x)
$$
Long story short, for all $g \in G \subset G * H$ and $h \in H \subset G * H$, $g \cdot h \neq h \cdot g$, but the following holds:
$$
f(g \cdot h) = f(g) \cdot f(h) = f(h) \cdot f(g) = f(h \cdot g)
$$
But what is the corresponding normal subgroup? That is, what is the normal subgroup $N$ of $G * H$ such that $(G * H)/N = G \times H$? I need a concrete description.

Nevermind, I should've reminded of kernels.

What can you say about the normal subgroup generated by ${[g,h]\mid g\in G, h\in H}$?

The kernel is the "cartesian subgroup" of $G*H$, which is the normal subgroup generated by all elements of the form $[g,h]$ with $g\in G$ and $h\in H$. And it is easier to define $f$ using the universal property than trying to do it recursively.
